# Under what circumstances are [ClassCleanup] and [TestCleanup] not run

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a set of MSTest test cases that use methods with those attributes to delete all rows from tables in the test db created after the tests are started; every once in a while I end up with a row from a one of the unit tests still in the DB.

Since I'm saving the test start time and deleting all records with timestamps more recent than it, the only way I can see for the records surviving is if the cleanup code wasn't called.

Comment: Are you referring to NUnit, MSTest or another testing framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first off, a "unit test" technically shouldn't touch the DB. But, I use NUnit for my integration tests too, so no biggie.

The only circumstances in which the cleanup methods wouldn't run in their entirety is if there were an error in the cleanup function, or an exception caused the runtime to shut down. The only ones that I know can do that are stack overflow and out-of-memory errors. Aborting a test from the debugger will also cause the cleanup phase to be skipped.

A more likely explanation, depending on your data access layer, is that you lost your DB connection and the cleanup function couldn't get a new one. That would generally indicate a need to make your DAL more robust, and also indicates that something you're not expecting is happening in the test to cause the DAL to break down.

Comment: at least some of these are what I'd consider to be more integration than strict unit testing; having only just inherited the project I'm still trying to get a feel for what the prior devs had done.  I've always felt the purists views on what should/not be done in the tests rather silly; especially since there isn't an equivalent parallel set of tools to run other automated tests.  The DB is running on local host, so losing the connection seems a bit unlikely to me.

Comment: How "silly" the rules for various levels of testing are depend on your working culture. A key difference, most of the time, is that unit tests run really fast, so they can be run on every checkin when using a CI server. I've seen integration test suites that take hours, and in any case you normally run those less often.

Answer (score 2):

If you are debugging the tests and you stop the debugger before the test run completes, this will not be called.