# MsTest TestCleanup method not called when an unhandled exception is thrown

Tags: c#, automation, mstest

I have a test which uses an external assembly to access UI features in the application we're testing. This assembly throws an exception of its own custom type if the UI is not in the appropriate state.

I've set up a TestCleanup method that kills the application's process (while a TestInitialize starts it) so that after a test run has been completed, the UI is restarted with a clean state.

This work well under regular conditions, however, whenever an exception from the referenced assembly is thrown, it never gets to the cleanup method and jumps straight ahead to the next test. This doesn't happen with exceptions thrown from the test itself, like AssertFailedException. I even tried throwing a basic Exception from the test, and it got to the cleanup method.

Comment: What kind of exception is being thrown?  If you put a try catch around it, do you catch it?  Is it really an exception or a hard crash?  Try and create a reproducible scenario that can be posted here.

Comment: It's a custom exception implemented in the external assembly, inheriting directly from Exception. It's a genuine, simple .net exception, no hard crash or anything of the sort. And yes, a try-catch block would catch it - but that means I'll have to surround every test with it and call Assert.Fail on catch.

However, as I mentioned in my original post, if I throw a System.Exception from the **test itself**, MSTest won't crash and will hit the Cleanup method as required.

Comment: Can you repro it using your own code?  I tried and couldn't re-create the scenario where the cleanup was not run.

Comment: The actual code is in an off-internet machine. I'll try rewriting it on my home PC and upload it later.

Answer (score 11):

If an exception is uncaught in TestInitialize, TestCleanup won't be called.

1. http://web.archive.org/web/20140310065725/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/694337/testcleanup-method-does-not-run-when-it-should
2. [When MSTest fails in TestInitialize, why doesn't TestCleanup get executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788466/when-mstest-fails-in-testinitialize-why-doesnt-testcleanup-get-executed)
3. [Under what circumstances are [ClassCleanup] and [TestCleanup] not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899770/under-what-circumstances-are-classcleanup-and-testcleanup-not-run)

Answer (score 1):

This unfortunately diverges from the way C# handles exceptions in constructors : when this happens, the finalizer is called.

Answer (score 1):

That was fixed in MsTest v2.

https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/250

Extract from the above link:

> This was a conscious compat break to give unit test writers a choice to cleanup partially
>   initialized methods.

Answer (score 0):

But you can directly call CleanUp method from the catch block

```
        [TestCleanup]
        public void Clenup()
        {
               ..............
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void Test1()
        {
            try
            {...................}
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                 Cleanup();
                 throw new Exception();
            }
         }
```